# Mobile instant messenger using MoSync 2.7

Tags: android, mobile, windows-mobile

How to develop a mobile instant messenger like whats app in mo sync.Can  any one guide me how to do it?
It should be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Twitter client you can get some inspiration from here:

http://www.mosync.com/content/building-html5-twitter-client-twist

And more info about how to write the UI parts can be found at http://www.mosync.com/content/fun-things-do-lovesms-example-application and 
http://www.mosync.com/content/coding-beyond-limits-writing-native-apps-html5javascript

The MoSync devteam are happy to support your project, why not post your progress and thoughts right here on SO!

best

Alex